# Not able to delete the data from hdfs, even after leaving safemode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I used this command to leave the safe mode

`hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

But even then, when I use this command to delete files

`hdfs dfs -rm -r /user/amandeep/share/`

It shows the following error

```
15/06/18 23:35:05 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
rm: Cannot delete /user/amandeep/share/lib/lib_20150615024237. Name node is in safe mode.
```

Comment: Are you using HA HDFS?  If so, the active namenode could still be in safemode.   

Are you able to do other tasks?  Put files, cp files, etc ?

Comment: I am not able to do other tasks too ..

Comment: If you tail the Namenode's logs, is there a reason it is not exiting safemode?

Comment: i think it says it has no memory and some blocks are corrupt ..