# Can't exit or forceExit from Hadoop safe mode

Tags: hadoop, safe-mode

I am trying to delete a folder in `hadoop`:

```
hadoop fs -rm -R /seqr-reference-data/GRCh37/all_reference_data
```

But it is giving me an error:

> INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
>   rm: Cannot delete /seqr-reference-data/GRCh37/all_reference_data. Name node is in safe mode.

I tried the solutions specified here:

[Name node is in safe mode. Not able to leave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave)

None of them work. It writes me `Safe mode is OFF` and then I see the same error. What else could I try doing?

> Update

Just found a `duplicate` thread but it has no answer:

[Not able to delete the data from hdfs, even after leaving safemode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922639/not-able-to-delete-the-data-from-hdfs-even-after-leaving-safemode)

Comment: Have you tried `hadoop -fs -rm -skipTrash...`?